# How to stop timer on button click and get timer values in php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, timer

```
var n = 60;
setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
function countDown(){
    n--;
    if (n > 0){
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    }
    //alert(n);
    document.getElementById("div_timer").innerHTML = n; 
}
```

this is my code for count down timer. when clicking the submit button, i need to stop the counter running and should return the counter value. please help...

Comment: html code for submit
<input type='submit' name='submit' value="Sumbit"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using setTimeout, use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and assign it to a variable, so you can clear it with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) by passing the variable you therefore defined as argument.

For example :

```
var n = 10; 
var f = setInterval(function() { 
    console.log("foo"); 
    n--; 
    if (n<=0) { 
        clearInterval(f) 
    }
}, 1000);
```

Then in your button click handler, just do a

```
clearInterval(f)
```

and you'll get the right **n** value.

Also note that the first step of the interval is occuring after 1s in my example, which technically makes **n** reaches 0 after 11s, not 10.

For the following, as your title is a bit weird (javascript php ?), after you get the **n** value, do an Ajax request to some php-server with **n value** as a parameter. But I think this should belong to another question.

Br.

Comment: thank you for the answer. when clicking a stop button in html, the stopped value or counter should be displayed.

<input type='button' name='stop' value="stop" onclick="clearInterval(f)"/>